# Получить байты и записать их в файл

Tags: c#

***ByteArray:*** Конвертировал через [HxD](https://mh-nexus.de/en/hxd/) (c#)

```
byte[] rawData = 
{
  0x4D, 0x5A, 0x90, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
  0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x1F, 0xBA, 0x0E, 0x00, 0xB4, 0x09, 0xCD,
  0x21, 0xB8, 0x01, 0x4C, 0xCD, 0x21, 0x54, 0x68
};
```

**Hex:** - так выглядит оригинальный файл закинутый в HxD

```
4D 5A 90 00 03 00 00 00 04 00 00 00 FF FF 00 00 B8 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
40 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
00 00 00 00 80 00 00 00 0E 1F BA 0E 00 B4 09 CD 21 B8 01 4C CD 21 54 68
```

---

Нашёл метод который получает Hex из бинарного файла

```
// 4D-5A-90-00-03-00-00-00-04-00-00-00-FF
// 4D5A90000300000004000000FF
public static void BitConvertToFile()
{
  var res = BitConverter.ToString(File.ReadAllBytes("build.exe"));

  var resdash = BitConverter.ToString(File.ReadAllBytes("build.exe")).Replace("-", string.Empty);

  File.WriteAllText("file.txt", resdash);
}
```

Вопрос: Как получить ByteArray (rawData) из Hex ( конвертировать его в байты ) и записать эту же последовательность байтов в файл .txt ?

---

В самом файле .txt должно быть содержимое такого текста:

```
0x4D, 0x5A, 0x90, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x1F, 0xBA, 0x0E, 0x00, 0xB4, 0x09, 0xCD,
0x21, 0xB8, 0x01, 0x4C, 0xCD, 0x21, 0x54, 0x68
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```cs
static void Main()
{
    byte[] rawData =
    {
        0x4D, 0x5A, 0x90, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
        0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x1F, 0xBA, 0x0E, 0x00, 0xB4, 0x09, 0xCD,
        0x21, 0xB8, 0x01, 0x4C, 0xCD, 0x21, 0x54, 0x68
    };

    // в текст
    string text = string.Join(", ", rawData.Select(x => "0x" + x.ToString("X2")));
    File.WriteAllText("file.txt", text);

    // из текста
    string hex = File.ReadAllText("file.txt");
    byte[] fileData = hex.Split(',').Select(x => Convert.ToByte(x.Trim(), 16)).ToArray();

    // сравнение побайтово
    Console.WriteLine(rawData.SequenceEqual(fileData));
    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Содержимое записанного файла

```
0x4D, 0x5A, 0x90, 0x00, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x04, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0xFF, 0xFF, 0x00, 0x00, 0xB8, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x40, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x80, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x0E, 0x1F, 0xBA, 0x0E, 0x00, 0xB4, 0x09, 0xCD, 0x21, 0xB8, 0x01, 0x4C, 0xCD, 0x21, 0x54, 0x68
```

Вывод в консоль

```
True
```

Это значит, что массивы идентичны